# There is a signature for a specific ABI in an ELF or binary file?

Tags: x86, arm, elf, abi

I need to identify the ABI used to generate some binaries, programs, dynamic and static libraries .

I would like to ask if there is a property or a tag or a string I can check with some external tool to see which ABI was used to create that binary object . My objects are mostly ELF for x86 and ARM, and I'm including ABIs for debugging purposes too like DWARF ones .

EDIT: something like the magic bytes at the start of a file that are generally used to detect the fileformat of a file .

Answer (score 6):

There are a several indicators which may be present in the ELF files.

1. the `EI_OSABI` field of the [ELF header ident](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.eheader.html#osabil)
2. the [`.note.ABI-tag`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_1.2.0/gLSB/noteabitag.html) used to mark e.g. [Linux vs. FreeBSD binaries](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2003-06/msg00487.html).
3. `FreeBSD` uses "branding" signature in the reserved part of the `e_indent` field (starting from the 8th byte).
4. For ARM files, you additionally have `EABI` version/variant info in the [`e_flags` field](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2012-09/msg00046.html), and the object files may also have the `.ARM.attributes` section
5. `.comment` section may contain compiler name/version, but it's informational only - it is not used by the OS to identify the ABI, and usually does not mention specific ABI information.
6. the `.note` section may contain additional info which could point to the ABI being used.

In most cases, `readelf` will display the necessary info, though you may need to add some switches (e.g. `-A` to display the `.ARM.attributes` section). I don't think there's anything to parse the `.note.ABI-tag` section so you may have to do it manually.

For more info, see the SysV ABI and ARM EABI docs.